# docker- django build image, but don't run in linux server

Tags: django, docker, tensorflow

in my ubuntu computer, I can build image and run with no error
[image]

but in linux server, when running, it stop at showing notification in red circle, than it is off but doesn't showing any error
[image]

I try building docker image with a simple django project (https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-docker/) and it runs without error in linux server

any idea to resolve this?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev\
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

##############################################################################################
#FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
#FROM python:3.6.1-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
#RUN python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade "Download URL"
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip 
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
#RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.7.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

update: my commmmmand.sh:

```
sudo docker build -t decaptcha:1.0 .
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 decaptcha:1.0
#sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 --rm -it $(sudo docker build -t decaptcha:1.0 -q .)
```

I coppy paste first line when build and second line when run in both computers

update 2:
[image]

[image]

Thank to manaclan for helping make it clearer for me (I am newbie in docker)

but when I jump into the docker container then run python file, there is no change

my linux server distro:
[image]

update 3:
[image]

this is my result when logging cpu and ram status with top, command in red circle is shown when running 'migrate' and in yellow circle is shown when running 'runserver'. I am thinking that I will run directly by Django instead of by Docker

Comment: what command did you run on your computer?

Comment: I have updated in my question
thanks for answering

Comment: logs seem fine, try changing `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` in your DockerFile to `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` then `sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 decaptcha:1.0` to jump into the docker container then run your python file to see what happen

Comment: I have updated in my question, any idea?
thank you

Comment: I suggest you posting error code not screenshot as it will be easier to just copy than typing your error to google

Comment: Also what is your linux server distro?

Comment: I will keep that in mind

but... there isn't any error shown; "traceback (most recent last call)" in update2 shown when I press Ctrl C, I want to check that it still runs; then I type "python3" to check that python still runs; then I type "make migrations", after about 2 mins, it is off but doesn't show any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239582/discussion-between-manaclan-and-lam-vu-nguyen).